# How can I get large picture of timeline (newsfeed) from Facebook using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm would like to get some feeds from my page timeline, displaying the text and picture of the posts. However, when I use the Graph API to get the posts, the "picture" object in the post object is always linking to a very small picture. The response is like this.

```
{
  "id": "519206795_10153078514666796", 
  "from": {
    "id": "519206795", 
    "name": "Kwun Yeung"
  }, 
  "message": "http://anacny2015.creativeworks.com.hk/receive/QguzqtooMy", 
  "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAE5bRyLZtnqOup&w=158&h=158&url=http%3A%2F%2Fanacny2015.creativeworks.com.hk%2Fimg%2Fcny%2Fcny_41.jpg", 
  "link": "http://anacny2015.creativeworks.com.hk/receive/QguzqtooMy",
......
```

The URL from the "picture" object is just a very small picture in 158x158 pixels and. Is it possible to get a large one just like what Facebook is showing on the timeline?

Thanks!